# SwiftUI Unexpected List/Core Data behavior

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

So, for starters, important snippets of my ContentView() struct:

1) Core Data fetching

```
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Rating.getAllRatings()) var ratings:FetchedResults<Rating>
```

2) ForEach view pushing RatingView() views from ratings

```
    ForEach(self.ratings) { rating in
        RatingView(rating: rating)
    }
```

3) RatingView() Rating() property

```
    var rating = Rating()
```

4) RatingView() conditional views

```
    HStack {
        if rating.isEditing?.boolValue ?? true {
            TextField("Enter Title", text: $newRatingName)
        }
        if rating.isEditing?.boolValue ?? true {
            Toggle()
        }
    }
```

Behavior I'm expecting: everything working like a charm.

Behavior I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHGCj.jpg
(Initially loaded views are displayed properly, while views lazy-loaded by ForEach are broken in a not entirely obvious way (a Toggle() is displayed, but it is not interactable, and TextField is not displayed at all).

Comment: Pretty sure you want the `rating` property of `RatingView` to `@ObservedObject var rating: Rating` so the `RatingView` is remade when `rating` is changed.

Comment: You're right, but pretty sure it's unrelated to my issue.

Comment: Known Apple issue with List + Toggle and/or TextField (actually originated in List), reported several times here on SO... Was not reproduced with Xcode 11.1 / iOS 13.1. You can try that environment or wait new with fixes. No known workarounds with List.